# calling a rails controller method with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I got a javascript funktion:

```
function handlePercentage(filledInPixels) {
  filledInPixels = filledInPixels || 0;
  console.log(filledInPixels + '%');
  if (filledInPixels > 80) {
    canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
  }
}
```

Now I want to access a rails controller to check a random string when `filledInPixels > 80`

How can I do that without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1):

Just make a `GET` or `POST` AJAX call to your Rails resource.

If you are using jQuery:

```
$.get( "/controller/action.json", { your: "params", another: "value" } )
  .done(function( data ) {
    // Access your data here
  });
```

Comment: or can I just access the `filledInPixels` variable in my controller?

Comment: Only if you pass it as a parameter in your ajax call: `$.get( "/controller/action.json", { filledInPixels: filledInPixels } );`.